# delete image on cloudinary using django

Tags: django, cloudinary

I have tried a few thing and i can't seem to find a solution to my problem , i want to check if the field of the form image1 has a new image in it and delete the old image in cloudinary but it doesnt delete anything with the code i have , i tried in the django shell and everything work fine. here's the code:

```
def edit_job(request, slug):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, user=request.user, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddJob(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=job)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form['image1']:
                cloudinary.uploader.destroy(job.image1, invalidate = True)
            form.save()
            return redirect('view_job', slug=job.slug)
    else:
        form = AddJob(instance=job)
    return render(request, 'jobs/edit_job.html', {'form': form, 'job': job})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your model looks like this:

```
  from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
  class CustomModel(models.Model):
       image = CloudinaryField('image',blank=True,null=True)
       user = models.OneToOneField(User,blank=True, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name=_('User'))
```

And in the view:

```
import cloudinary.uploader
import cloudinary
import CustomModel.models

custommodel= CustomModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
cloudinary.uploader.destroy(custommodel.image.public_id,invalidate=True)
```

You probably can't delete the photo because you didn't pass public_id to Cloudinary. **public_id** is an attribute in the CloudinaryField.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract the `public_id` of the resource from a `CloudinaryResource` object using the `public_id` property.